# How to count words in a file using python >2.0

Tags: python, computer-science

I want to write a program that can count keywords in a file.
Example: I created a list, with the following keywords. Then I open a file with bunch of words, and I want to count how many keywords are there in the file. But no matter what I do, the count will always give me 0. What did I do wrong?

Here is my code:

```
Happy = ['amazed', 'amazing', 'best', 'excellent', 'excited', 'excite', 
         'excites', 'exciting', 'glad', 'greatest', 'happy', 'love',
         'loves', 'loved', 'loving', 'lovin', 'prettiest']

def CountFile():
  file = open("File.txt", "r")
  Count = 0
  for i in file:
    i = i.split()
    if i in Happy:
      count = count + 1
  print("there are" count "keywords")
  return

CountFile()
```

Comment: @Julien I just started learning python, I couldn’t really understand that code.

Comment: Why should I care? Read a tutorial...

Comment: @Julien the accepted answer for your link is only for python 2.What if someone want to do that in python 3 or easier than that method ?

Comment: @yacc I did, but like I said I just started learning python, I couldnt really understand some of the code

Comment: @sachindubey this question has been asked and answered a million times. A tiny bit of research effort will give you 10 different solutions to choose from.

Comment: @Qwert you missed one for loop after split...Try my code it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

`Happy = ['amazed', 'amazing', 'best', 'excellent', 'excited', 'excite', 
         'excites', 'exciting', 'glad', 'greatest', 'happy', 'love',
         'loves', 'loved', 'loving', 'lovin', 'prettiest']`

```
def CountFile():
   file = open("File.txt", "r")
   count = 0
   for i in file:
      i = i.split()
      for so in i:
         if so in Happy:  
            count = count + 1
   print("there are %s keywords" %count)

CountFile()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `i = i.split()`

`i` becomes a list. Your `i` variable is a line in your text file here.

You can probably do,

```
   ...
   words = i.split()
   for w in words:     
     if w in Happy:
       count += 1
   ...
```